# Get Progress from Three Values

Tags: calculus, analysis, statistics

I have a starting weight, current weight and target weight.
How can I get a percentage of progress?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume you expect your progress curve to be linear.

We want to see how far along the path we are. Our current progress is current weight - starting weight:  $$\delta W = W_C - W_S.$$

Our total progression is our target weight - starting weight:

$$\Delta W = W_T - W_S.$$

100 times the ratio of these is our percentage:

$$\%\ \textrm{complete} = 100 \times \frac{\delta W}{\Delta W} = 100 \times \frac{W_C - W_S}{W_T - W_S}.$$

Note that if current weight = target weight, we have

$$\frac{W_C - W_S}{W_C - W_S} = 1 = 100\%.$$